# How to show the pin after input in textbox

Tags: javascript, google-maps

How can i show the Adress i put in to 4 textboxes (Pin Changing after onchange)
on the Google map on my website?
I want to have 4 input fields (zip, city, street and house number)
If there are more than 4 letters than he have to show me the adress on card

i tried the democode from download page

```
  $(function(){

$('#test').gmap3({
      map:{
        options:{
          center:[46.721976,14.180603],
          zoom:8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
          mapTypeControl: false,
          mapTypeControlOptions: false,
          navigationControl: false,
          scrollwheel: false,
          streetViewControl: false
        }
      }
    });


    $('#test-address').keydown(function(e){
      var addr = $('#test-address').val();
      if ( !addr || !addr.length ) return;
      $("#test").gmap3({
        getlatlng:{
          address:  addr,
          callback: function(results){
            if ( !results ) return;
            $(this).gmap3({
              marker:{
    latLng:results[0].geometry.location,
                map:{
                  center: true
                }
              }
            });
          }
        }
      });
    });

  });
```

but i need this from 4 input boxes combined.

how can i do this?

Comment: What does your HTML look like?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

In Html code i have the Input Box and the Gmap Div

This is from the demo folder. 
I need the combination of 4 input boxes (zip, city, street, housenumber) instead the 1 input box and the demo script adds pins without remove the input i done before (if i change the adress)